# Program crashes after several mins or when resumed after being idle for few mins

Tags: android, parse-platform

i have an error that I cannot troubleshoot. The program works but when the device is idle and I resume to the application it crashes. Basically, what my codes does it gets an invitation from a user. It displays invitations received from severals users, I have the option to accept or reject the invitation. 0 means rejected invitation and 1 accepts the invitation. I am using parse for BaaS. I get this error and cannot trouble shoot please need some assistance:

Error:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.Object android.content.Context.getSystemService(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference
            at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.init(ArrayAdapter.java:310)
            at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.<init>(ArrayAdapter.java:153)
            at com.example.davchen.skibuddies.Fragments.InviteTab$2.<init>(InviteTab.java:93)
            at com.example.davchen.skibuddies.Fragments.InviteTab.updateList(InviteTab.java:92)
            at com.example.davchen.skibuddies.Fragments.InviteTab.access$200(InviteTab.java:35)
            at com.example.davchen.skibuddies.Fragments.InviteTab$1.done(InviteTab.java:81)
            at com.example.davchen.skibuddies.Fragments.InviteTab$1.done(InviteTab.java:69)
            at com.parse.ParseTaskUtils$2$1.run(ParseTaskUtils.java:115)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5942)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1399)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1194)
```

Below is my code:

```
public class InviteTab extends Fragment {

    private static final String TAG = InviteTab.class.getSimpleName();

    private List<Invitation> invites;
    private ListView inviteList;
    private Invitation invitation;

    public InviteTab() {}

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        invites =  new ArrayList<Invitation>();
        invitation = new Invitation();
    }

   // @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        //return super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.invite_tab_fragment, container, false);
        inviteList = (ListView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.invitationList);
        queryEventListFromParse();
        return rootView;
    }

    private void queryEventListFromParse() {

        ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery("Invitation");
        query.whereEqualTo("Participants", ParseUser.getCurrentUser());
        query.whereEqualTo("Status", "0");
        query.include("EventId");
        query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() {
            @Override
            public void done(List<ParseObject> Objects, ParseException e) {
                if (e == null) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "Check if program enters loop");
                    invites.clear();
                    for (ParseObject EventInvite : Objects) {
                        invites.add((Invitation) EventInvite);
                    }
                    Log.d(TAG, String.valueOf(invites.size()));
                    updateList(); //update the list
                } else {
                    Log.d(TAG, "Unable to retreive Invites: " + e.getMessage());
                }

            }
        });
    }

    private void updateList() {

        ArrayAdapter<Invitation> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<Invitation>(getActivity(),
                R.layout.invitation_list, invites) {
            @Override
            public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

                if(convertView==null) {
                    convertView = getActivity().getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.invitation_list, parent, false);
                }
                TextView Title = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.eventName);
                Button button1 =(Button)convertView.findViewById(R.id.acceptButton);
                Button button2 = (Button)convertView.findViewById(R.id.rejectButton);
                //TextView tvStart = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView_start);
               // TextView tvEnd = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView_end);

                invitation = invites.get(position);

                Title.setText(invitation.getEventId().get("EventTitle").toString());
//                tvStart.setText(event.getStartTime());
//                tvEnd.setText(event.getEndTime());

                button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        updateStatus(position);
                    }
                });

                return convertView;
            }

            @Override
            public int getCount() {
                return super.getCount();
            }
        };

        Log.d(TAG, "Was in adapter method");
        inviteList.setAdapter(adapter);

    }

    private void updateStatus(int position) {
        Invitation invite = invites.get(position);

        invite.setUserId(ParseUser.getCurrentUser());
        invite.setFlag("1");
        invite.saveInBackground(new SaveCallback() {
            @Override
            public void done(ParseException e) {
                if(e==null) {
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), "Accepted Request", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
                else{
                    Log.e(TAG, e.getMessage());
                }
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Context context) {
        super.onAttach(context);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDetach() {
        super.onDetach();
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        queryEventListFromParse();
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (resultCode == getActivity().RESULT_OK) {
            // If a new event has been added, update the list of events
            Log.d(TAG, "Hello");
            queryEventListFromParse();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You are getting null pointer exception in array list, as you said you are trying to resume the app, I think, it is not able to retrieve the value(invitation value) because of which the default null value is getting passed and which crashes the app, try to save the value in shared preferences, and check your logs for e.getMessage(), I think it will give you better insights(as it will print if it is not able to retrieve invites)

Comment: Maybe you should init parse again after resume.It's my guess.I have never use Parse.

Comment: @tinysunlight i ddi invoke the query method in the onResume() function

Comment: Can you check wheher getActivity() or invites is null in updatelist?I think getActivity() is null.

Comment: I have a bad idea .Your app will not crash .But the fragment will not show too.In you activity, override onSaveInstanceState and do nothing in it.

Comment: @tinysunlight will try that

Comment: It's because system restore fragment and doesn't restore activity .And in the fragment getActivity() is null.

Comment: @tinysunlight i did that and the app did not crash so far

Comment: @tinysunlight no it actually just crashed now

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/97765/discussion-between-tiny-sunlight-and-user3497437).

Comment: You shouldn't put fragment'code in onResume.If you put code in it ,it will trigger once  you change to other activity and go back.

Comment: If you add if(getActivity() == null)return in updatlist ,what will happen.

Comment: i added it but still crashes after few mins switching tabs

Comment: So what's the new errorlog?Move code in onresume to onCreateView and viewpager.setoffsetlist(10) in the activity contain this fragment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use `getActivity()` method be'coz fragment de attached
 when app goes in background and open after while.

see [fragment life cycle](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html#Creating)

Initilize `context` while attach fragment to actvity

```
@Override
public void onAttach(Activity context) {
    super.onAttach(context);
    this.context = context;
}
```

put you code in `onActivityCreated` and use `context` rather than `getActivity()`

```
 @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    queryEventListFromParse();

}
```

Comment: should it be context or getContext() in View on Create Method

Comment: Have you seen life cycle? `onCreate()` and `onCreateView()` execute before `onActivityCreated` so its possible that `getActvity()` return `null`. that why put your methods after activity create (onActivityCreated)

Comment: @kishorejethave so basically after activity has been created pass the method queryEventListFromParse() in onActivityCreated

Comment: yes put in `onActivityCreated` first try without `context`

Comment: so should i also remove queryEventListFromParse from onCreateView() as well

Comment: Ok thanks will do so. I tried with context and no crash. Should i try with getActivity

Comment: @kishorejethave thanks for the help. Should i attempt getActivity() or stay with context

Comment: stay with context it wouldn't betray.!!